# size_t redefined in calcstar

Tags: c++, expression, eval

I need to use calcstar that is math expression evaluator...
I just simply include calcstar.h file and it include everything else

```
#include "calcstar.h"
```

but when I try to compile my code i get this error:

> `size_t` redefined

This error appears inside calcstar's own files...but the point is that this library is published online so I assume it is tested and doesn't have a bug...

What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

I really need a mathematical expression evaluator for my project.

Comment: Where did you get `calcstar.h`?  What is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: You need to show us the code that triggers the error.

Comment: anyone can publish buggy code online.

Comment: Ah, "this library is published online, so it shouldn't be a bug". That's my favourite quote of the whole day.

Comment: Is it intended for use with Visual Studio?  The VS compilers allow redefinitions of typedefs as long as they're compatible.  GCC and friends don't.

Comment: @KerrekSB: even more special when you consider it's probably coming from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/747223/CalcStar-A-Cplusplus-Math-Expression-Evaluator).

Comment: Update: I downloaded it and it's a VS2008 project.  I think that explains your problem.

Comment: @djikay: It has five stars! And it's so standard, it's spelled `Std::string`. [Edit] Wait what, it's written by C3PO!

Comment: just to remind u friends this is calcstar library in code project http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/747223/CalcStar-A-Cplusplus-Math-Expression-Evaluator

Comment: so what should i do if it is VS2008 u mean i can't used it with qt? i want to use this library for my qt guy application....what solution u give ?

Answer (score 2):

CalcStar, assuming you got it from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/747223/CalcStar-A-Cplusplus-Math-Expression-Evaluator), was apparently developed using Visual Studio 2008 (the download file name is `CalcStarApp_VS2008_03202014.zip`.).

One of the quirks of Visual Studio is that it allows redefinition of `typedef`s.  Other compilers (like the one you appear to be using) do not.

You'll need to modify code appropriately.